# Unknown error in Repast: does not find some module?

Tags: java, agent-based-modeling, repast-simphony

I am launching a model that was created with an old version of repast (RepastSimphony 1.2.0) and I am trying to run it an the latest version of Repast.

I have imported manually the scenarios files to the best of my abilities (I am a beginner with Repast).

Now, when I launch the model in Repast, it has en error because it cannot find a certain file/library/module (I am unsure).

Now, I am not sure whether this is a Repast internal library or some piece of code that I should have been given and that is missing...

Any insight about this error will be welcome !

The error is this one:

```
WARN  [AWT-EventQueue-0] 13:20:38,158 ObjectActionLoader - Error loading information from data. Continuing with model loading.
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: repast.score.impl.SGeographyImpl : repast.score.impl.SGeographyImpl
---- Debugging information ----
message             : repast.score.impl.SGeographyImpl
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : repast.score.impl.SGeographyImpl
class               : java.util.ArrayList
required-type       : java.util.ArrayList
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
path                : /repast.simphony.visualization.engine.DefaultDisplayDescriptor/projections/repast.score.impl.SGeographyImpl
line number         : 61
class[1]            : repast.simphony.visualization.engine.DefaultDisplayDescriptor
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
version             :
```

I traced that the attempt to load something from the scenario description:

```
    <repast.score.impl.SGeographyImpl>
      <name>PeopleGeography</name>
    </repast.score.impl.SGeographyImpl>
  </projections>
  <valueLayers/>
  <projectionDescriptors>
    <entry>
      <string>PeopleGeography</string>
      <repast.simphony.visualization.engine.DefaultProjectionDescriptor>
        <proj class="repast.score.impl.SGeographyImpl" reference="../../../../projections/repast.score.impl.SGeographyImpl"/>
        <props/>
      </repast.simphony.visualization.engine.DefaultProjectionDescriptor>
    </entry>
  </projectionDescriptors>
```

Incidentally, I tried to run a model from the model library (zombies) and it launches and works properly.

Comment: Is repast.score.impl.SGeographyImpl a legacy module? I cannot find it in the Repast documentation. Or could it be some homemade module ?

Comment: I found that DefaultProjectionDescriptor precisely used in the model I was given is DEPRECATED in Repast documentation. 
Does the fact that it is deprecated means that it can cause an error or is it only advised not to use it but it's still there for backward compatibility (and then the error is coming from somewhere else) ?